# I keep getting the error message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_facecolor' in python

Tags: python-3.x

So I defined a function to plot a graph which looks like this:

```
def plot_by_date(df,countries,log,title,xtitle,ytitle):

    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.set_facecolor('whitesmoke')
    plt.grid(True, linewidth=1, color='dimgrey',linestyle=':')

    df=df.loc[countries].T
    plt.plot(df) #linestyle="--"
    plt.legend(df.columns,bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.,frameon=False)

    xmin=0;xmax=90;ymin=10;ymax=1000000
    ax.set_xlim(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax)
    ax.set_ylabel(ytitle)
    ax.set_xlabel(xtitle)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xticklabels(df.T.columns, rotation = 70)

    n = 3  # Keeps every 7th xlabel
    [l.set_visible(False) for (i,l) in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()) if i % n != 0]

    if log==1:
        ax.set_yscale('log')
    return plt.show()
```

Which ran without an issue, but when I tried to plot it using actual values like so:

```
df=active_grouped
countries=['Singapore','Korea, South','India','Pakistan','Iran','Australia','US','Spain','Italy','China','Germany']
log=1
title='Active Cases'
xtitle='Date'
ytitle='Active Cases (log scale)'

plot_by_date(df,countries,log,title,xtitle,ytitle)
```

I get the eroor message. Removing the setfacecolor attribute gives the  same error for xlim, or ylim or whatever. I am so confused can someone help me out

Comment: Hi ! Can you give full the error you have please (with the traceback) ?
And also the import you've done

Comment: The import (active grouped) is a dataframe I created. There are no problems with it. I dont understand what you mean by the import

Comment: Well, have you done any `import ... as plt`, or any other import ? What is inside `plt` and `active_grouped`? And can you give the traceback so that we can locate exactly the error ?

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-9cd0d0762552> in <module>
      6 ytitle='Active Cases (log scale)'
      7 
----> 8 plot_by_date(df,countries,log,title,xtitle,ytitle)
      9 
     10 

<ipython-input-19-7539586a7547> in plot_by_date(df, countries, log, title, xtitle, ytitle)
      3     fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
      4     ax = fig.add_subplot()
----> 5     ax.set_facecolor('whitesmoke')
      6     plt.grid(True, linewidth=1, color='dimgrey',linestyle=':')
      7

Comment: Thats the traceback, with the following error message at the end: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_facecolor'

Comment: Ive only used matplotlib.pyplot as plt nothing else, active_grouped contains the active covid 19 cases grouped by country, so the graph shoud show active cases by date how it varies by country